# How to associate nested models with dynamic finders in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to seed my db with data from CSVs for a Rails 4 app. I decided to do that treatment in my app creating my own import function. Here is an example of the import function in my `Film` model. In my CSV the firstname and lastname of the director are associated with the film's name in each row.

```
CSV.foreach(path, :col_sep => ",", :quote_char => "\x00", :headers => true) do |row|
        hash = row.to_hash
      hash.values.each do |value|
        value.strip! unless value.nil? # remove whitespaces around
      end

        unless hash["name"].blank?
            film  = find_or_create_by name: hash["name"]
        unless hash["firstname"].blank? && hash["lastname"].blank?
          film.director = Director.find_or_create_by firstname: hash["firstname"], lastname: hash["lastname"]
        end
      end

    end
```

My films and directors are created but not associated to each other (i.e. `director_id` fields in my `films` table are empty).
I assume this line would need a fix:

`film.director = Director.find_or_create_by firstname: hash["firstname"], lastname: hash["lastname"]`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning `film.director`, the change is not automatically persisted in the database, you need to apply one of these two solutions:

```
director = Director.find_or_create_by(firstname: hash["firstname"], lastname: hash["lastname"])

# Solution #1:
film.update_attributes(director: director)

# Solution #2:
film.director = director
film.save
```